# How can I join result from two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So sorry but I am new to SQL querying and could use a little help.

I will like to join results from 2 tables and I can't seem to get it return results I need.

Query 1

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7
from t1
where (c3 between cast(dateadd(day, -1,Getdate()) AS Date and cast(dateadd(day,0,getdate()) as date))
```

Query 2

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6
from t2
where c2 in ('user', 'connected', 'agent') and
(c3 between cast(dateadd(day, -1,Getdate()) AS Date and cast(dateadd(day,0,getdate()) as date))
```

I tried using union all but I get an error must have equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear to other people what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an union, both queries must have the same number of fields in the select statements. Query 1 has 7 items while query 2 has 6. You can add a null value to query 2.

Comment: I am getting error  conversion failed when converting date/time from character string. c1 is int.

Comment: I was able to figure it out by reordering columns.